# MySQL run query if previous query is not null

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures

I am trying to run two queries where the second query will run only if the first is not null. Something like:

```
    if((select * from abc where id =1)!=null)
      select * from cde
    else exit;
```

what is the proper way to perform such operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use exists condition

only if `select 1 from abc where id =1`  return at least one record `select * from cde` will be executed

```
 select * from cde
    where exists (select 1 from abc where id =1 )
```

if you need execute other statements you can use something like follows

```
  if exits (SELECT 1 from abc where id =1) then
   --  select a into var_x from cde...
   --  upddate ...
 else
   --  
 end if;
```

Comment: can this be used to call a procedure as in call procedure() if exits (select * from abc) ?

Comment: yes, but i was not sure, i have just edited my answer